# Is it possible to define single arguments as parameters in Java?

Tags: java

i am wondering if it is possible to define parameters for a command line program directly in the main function as parameters, like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(double a1, double a2) {
        //do something with a1, a2...
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //do something with args[0], args[1]
    }
}
```

Comment: no, `main` is a defined entry point. You cannot change it's signature

Comment: nop you can only an array of strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not allowed by the Java language specification.

To quote it:

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
>   String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1

Comment: thanks alot for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yep it's possible.  **You can't create your own parameters tho.**  The args[] variable can already handle those passed values. You just need to access the value in every command line argument by calling args[0]...args[n].

Example:
String option = args[0];
System.out.println(option);

Test:
java myProgram.java -sampleArgument

Result:
-sampleArgument

Answer (score 1):

I got somes bas new for you... It's not possible directly. The jvm will always search for a method with the following signature as an entry point of your program (I'ts a standart, it will problably never change):

```
public static void main(String ... args)
```

I know that the "String ... args" may seems odd but it's just another notation for the "String [] args". 
However, you can still call them , one after another by doing that:

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    System.out.println(args[0]);//if there is one argument
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can define a *main* method that takes any kind of parameter.

But when you intend to use that *main* method as "entry point" (by telling the JVM to to invoke the corresponding class), sorry, that will not work.

The JVM only allows you to run a main that is defined as public static void and taking an array of Strings.

But of course, there are many libraries out there that help there: for example by allowing you to "define" expected command line arguments and their type. Meaning: you don't have to constantly re-invent the wheel to turn the command line arguments into that thing you need; you can specify "i want this or that" and get going from there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200054/java-library-for-parsing-command-line-parameters) for some libraries around this topic.